# How to locate multiple widget of same type in widget hierarchy?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-integration-test

I am developing some intregration tests for one of my flutter-web application. I wanted to specifically locate the container(width: 50, height: 50) in the following below widget hierarchy tree considering top to bottom approach.
ParentWidget --> Row --> Text, SizedBox, Row --> Container(), **Container(width: 50, height: 50)**, Container().
**Note: Without key approach**

I tried to locate using descendant of ParentWidget --> Row --> Row --> with index tried to select the 2nd container, but this isn't working, it fails with error *"Bad state: No element"*.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ParentWidget({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text("Hello World..!!"),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 20,
              height: 20,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 20,
              height: 20,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
final container = tester.widget<Container>(find.descendant(
    of: find.descendant(
        of: find.byType(ParentWidget), matching: find.byType(Row)),
    matching: find.descendant(
        of: find.byType(Row), matching: find.byType(Container).at(1))));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find multiple widgets in a test you can do this:

```dart
testWidgets('Test containers', (tester) async {
    
    await tester.pumpWidget(ParentWidget());

    expect(find.byType(Container), findsNWidgets(3));
  });
```

For more info check https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/widget/introduction

Edit:
To test the second Container's width you could do something like this:

```dart
//get the second element's widget, index 1, cast it as a container and check its width
expect((find.byType(Container).evaluate().elementAt(1).widget as Container).constraints?.maxWidth, 50.0);
```

Comment: Above testcase  asserts for 3 container presence inside ParentWidget ....but i want to specifically locate the 2nd container and fetch its property like width and height etc...
FYI: ParentWidget is just the subpart of the entire widget tree

Comment: @RajeshPatil I've added a test case to test the width of the second container. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If your widget tree is deep nested and you want to locate specific widget down the tree we can make use of something:
If sub-widget tree contains multiple widget of same type...try locating it via index...how the look up will going to work is, it will try to locate the 2nd Container down under the `ParentWidget` sub tree.

```
final container = (find
          .descendant(
              of: find.byType(ParentWidget),
              matching: find.byType(Container),
              matchRoot: true)
          .evaluate()
          .elementAt(1)
          .widget as Container);
```